# How to read a csv file that has data with rows over two lines

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file which consists of entries like this:

```
no|letter|year
13951981|D
|2019
14965824|G
|2019
10734377|D
|2019
1419736|K|2014
1514653|K|2014
8398443|B|2014
```

However the format should have been:

```
no|letter|year
13951981|D|2019
14965824|G|2019
10734377|D|2019
1419736|K|2014
1514653|K|2014
8398443|B|2014
```

As a result the data is being read with null values like so:

```
no      | letter | year
13951981|D       |NULL
NULL    |NULL    |2019
```

Is there a way of correctly reading this data? Or do I have to find a way to edit the csv file? Or is there a way of merging rows when necessary?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to manipulate the data, rather than finding a correct way of reading it. The code below results in a matrix, so a little more data work will be needed to turn it into a data.frame. It's important to note that the matrix will coerce all columns to character valued.

```
# read in using `text` argument
d <- read.table(text = tt, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# split at pipe delimiter, remove blanks
clean1 <- unlist(strsplit(d$V1, split = "|", fixed = TRUE))
clean1 <- clean1[clean1!=""]
# put into matrix
matrix(clean1, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

#      [,1]       [,2] [,3]  
# [1,] "13951981" "D"  "2019"
# [2,] "14965824" "G"  "2019"
# [3,] "10734377" "D"  "2019"
# [4,] "1419736"  "K"  "2014"
# [5,] "1514653"  "K"  "2014"
# [6,] "8398443"  "B"  "2014"
```

#### Data

```
tt <- "13951981|D
|2019
14965824|G
|2019
10734377|D
|2019
1419736|K|2014
1514653|K|2014
8398443|B|2014"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to fix the broken input file from the command line. Let us assume, that the file name is *broken.csv*, then the following one liner does the trick (tested only on OSX, but on Linux it should work equally well):

```
cat broken.csv | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/ |/|/g' | tr ' ' '\n' >fixed.csv
```

As *sed* is designed to only work with one line at a time, I use a hacky workarund:

- use *tr* to replace newlines with a unique character not occuring in the file (in this case a space)
- use *sed* to remove the special character when it occurs directly before the field separator ('|' in your case)
- use *tr* to replace the special character again with newline

Answer (score 0):

here is an other approach..

```
tt <- "13951981|D
|2019
14965824|G
|2019
10734377|D
|2019
1419736|K|2014
1514653|K|2014
8398443|B|2014"

data.table::fread( gsub( "\n\\|", "|", tt), sep = "|", header = FALSE )

#          V1 V2   V3
# 1: 13951981  D 2019
# 2: 14965824  G 2019
# 3: 10734377  D 2019
# 4:  1419736  K 2014
# 5:  1514653  K 2014
# 6:  8398443  B 2014
```